# log10 transformation in R

Tags: r, transformation

i have a question about data transformation. I want to transform a variable called `zinc` using `log10` transformation in R

Does anyone know how can i do it ?

Answer (score 8):

Just use

```
log10(zinc)
```

And assign it to the appropriate object (*e.g.* the dataframe where zinc is contained).

Answer (score 8):

You may need to do log10(zinc + 1) if any of the values in zinc are zero, since log10(0) is undefined.

I found [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5571wc0iWCI) useful in explaining log10 in R.